# MethodInfo.GetParameter() with Nullable type

Tags: c#, reflection, nullable

I have a need to invoke methods using reflection. below was my method need to be invoked:

```
public static void DoUpdate(int? operatorId, string name, string desc)
{
    // ...do some update work here...
}
```

i first need to grasp the parameters of this method, right? so i did this code:

```
public static object[] GetMethodParms(MethodInfo method, NameValueCollection coll)
{
    var parms = method.GetParameters();
    // ...do some parse work here...
}
```

well, then someting i thought was weird happend. as you can see, parameter "operatorId" was Nullable, but parms[0] shows that it was just a plain "System.Int32".

why this happend, can somebody give me a explain?

thanks in advance.

**edit#1**

my apologize. i should clarify these:

**.** i do know i can check whether a type was Nullable by the following code:

```
if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) 
{ … }
```

or, here is another way:

```
var IsNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ParameterType) !=null;
```

**.** i do not know why MethodInfo.GetParameter() return a plain underlying type for a Nullable(T) parameter. in my case, the "int? operatorId" return "System.Int32", which i expect to be a Nullable(int).

Answer (score 1):

you can check Nullable types as below

```
var parms = method.GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo p in parms)
{
    var IsNullable = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ParameterType) !=null;
}
```

[**`Nullable.GetUnderlyingType`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.getunderlyingtype.aspx) will return `null` in case of not `Nullable` type.

normally we can check for nullable types as below

```
System.Type type = typeof(int?);
Console.WriteLine(type.FullName); // System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

but when we use reflection at run time it will give the underline type not the nullbale type.

```
int? i = 5;
Type t = i.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(t.FullName); //"System.Int32"
```

Reason explained in MSDN as below

> Calling GetType on a Nullable type causes a boxing operation to be
>   performed when the type is implicitly converted to Object. Therefore
>   GetType always returns a Type object that represents the underlying
>   type, not the Nullable type.

Comment: yes, thank you Damith. you got these from this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/ms366789(v=vs.100).aspx, right? :)  but you know, the MethodInfo.GetParameters() was provide by microsoft, we cant change the inner code. i want to know why ms chosen this behavior, cant they just return a nullable type for me?

Comment: again, thank you Damith. this is a good way to check Nullable Type. nice to hear that.